# Xcode Collision Detection Error Cocos2D Assertion Error

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, assertion

I am making a ball game in cocos2D, where you can slide the ball in a direction, and it will travel until it collides with a wall. My collision detection is giving me an "assertion error" when I swipe the ball in a direction.

I am using tiledmap to make the levels.

The way I've coded it is that I find the tilesize that my ball is in, then, in a for loop, I check if there are any wall sprites around the ball.

Any ideas where its going wrong?

```objective-c
-(void)callEveryFrame:(ccTime)dt{

     //Error Here vvv (Assertion Failure in -[CCTMXLayer tileAt:])


     NSLog(@"First Touch x:  /%f  Last Touch x: /%f  First Touch y: /%f   Last Touch y:       /%f", firstTouch.x, lastTouch.x, firstTouch.y, lastTouch.y);

     if(swipeLeft || swipeRight || swipeDown || swipeUp)
     {
         bool collision = false;
         int ballTileX = (player.position.x / level1.tileSize.width);
         int ballTileY = (player.position.y / level1.tileSize.width);
         int collisionAreaX = ballTileX-1;
         int collisionAreaY = ballTileY-1;

         for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
         {
             bool tilePresent = [background tileAt:CGPointMake(collisionAreaX, collisionAreaY)] != NULL;

             if(tilePresent && CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRectMake(collisionAreaX*level1.tileSize.width, collisionAreaY*level1.tileSize.height, level1.tileSize.width, level1.tileSize.height), CGRectMake(ballTileX*level1.tileSize.width, ballTileY*level1.tileSize.height, level1.tileSize.width, level1.tileSize.height)))
             {
                 collision = true;
                 break;
             }

             if(i % 3 == 0)
             {
                 collisionAreaX -= 2;
                 collisionAreaY++;
             }
             else
             {
                 collisionAreaX++;
             }
         }

         if(collision) {
             swipeLeft = false;
             swipeRight = false;
             swipeDown = false;
             swipeUp = false;
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: post the exact error message as printed in the debug console (log). Could be tile coord out of bounds.

Comment: Here's the error:

2013-06-07 15:33:09.035 Test1a[25124:15203] *** Assertion failure in -[CCTMXLayer tileAt:], /Users/barneychambers/Documents/Test1a/Test1a/libs/cocos2d/CCTMXLayer.m:263

Comment: and the actual message? It's either "invalid position" or "map has been released". I bet it's the former so check the tileAt coords and figure out why they're out of bounds.

Comment: Hi Barney, are exception breakpoints enabled? If not, try to enable it to get information of what code have problem. To enable exception breakpoints, take a look at this: [link]http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions